# Contain a VB6 form in a .Net MDI

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vb6, mdi

I'm porting an old VB6 app into .Net but one Vb6 form is too big to migrate in this release.

I Shell the Vb6 exe to show the VB6 form from .Net, but the VB6 form is not contained in the .Net MDI. I have a gut feeling its not possible to **embed the VB6 form in the .NET MDI**, does anyone know if this is possible?

I'm after something like [Interop Forms Toolkit 2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb419144.aspx) or even an API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible. It's just neither simple, nor a particularly a good idea...

You'll need to create an ActiveX container for the form, which you can then embed the VB 6 form into. See this article on CodeProject for details: [Embedding of VB6 form in .NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6formsinNET.aspx)

Another possible (and significantly simpler approach) might be to set the parent of your VB 6 form as the .NET MDI container. I'm not actually sure if this will work (I've never tried it), but it's worth a shot. You'll need to P/Invoke the [`FindWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) to get the handle to your VB 6 form window, as well as the [`SetParent` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541.aspx) to change its parent window.

Comment: I agree Cody that its not a good idea. I'm going to keep with shelling the VB6 exe - so the business know we have more work to do!

Comment: BTW, the last idea is what we were previously doing.... SetParent(childForm.Handle, _parentHandle)
SendMessage(_parentHandle, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, IntPtr.Zero)
UpdateWindow(_parentHandle)

Comment: @Jeremy: So the second idea does actually work? It seemed to me like it should, but not having tried it myself, I couldn't be sure. I think that's much simpler than the first option, and since ultimately the goal should be a complete migration, there seems little point in spending so much time on intermedia interop. (Amazing how fast you get an answer on here sometimes, isn't it?)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I posted too soon here's the solution:

[Embedding of VB6 form in .NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6formsinNET.aspx)