# Underyling form disappearing but only if dialog shown

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6, com-interop, z-order

This relates to a VB6 app that shows a C# form via interop.

An event in the C# form causes one of the VB6 app forms to show.

Usually, when this VB6 form is made to be hidden (`Form.Hide`) the underlying C# form is brought to the front.

But if during its life-time the VB6 form has caused a `MsgBox` to be shown, then the underlying C# form will not be at the front when the VB6 form is made to be hidden.

Why does this happen?  It's like the `MsgBox` is changing the Z-Order of the forms.

Answer (score 1):

*"How do I cause the C# form to show after the VB6 is hidden? Do I have to use window handles?"*

Assuming you are ok with the orphaned msgbox being kept open. When the VB6 form is Hidden you need to fire an event to get the Window Handle:

```
public static int FindWindow(string windowName, bool wait)
{
    int hWnd = FindWindow(null, windowName);
    while (wait && hWnd == 0)
    {
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
         hWnd = FindWindow(null, windowName);
    }

    return hWnd;
}
```

Then bring the C# window to the Top:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

// When you don't want the ProcessId, use this overload and pass IntPtr.Zero for the second parameter
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

/// <summary>The GetForegroundWindow function returns a handle to the foreground window.</summary>
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool BringWindowToTop(HandleRef hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint nCmdShow);

private static void ForceForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    uint foreThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);
    uint appThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
    const uint SW_SHOW = 5;

    if (foreThread != appThread)
    {
        AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, true);
        BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
        AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, false);
    }
    else
    {
        BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
}
```

Ref: [SetForegroundWindow Win32-API not always works on Windows-7](http://www.shloemi.com/2012/09/solved-setforegroundwindow-win32-api-not-always-works/)

Comment: What about the `NativeWindow` class found down the bottom here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lt/vbinterop/thread/2692df26-317c-4415-816b-d08fe6854df8

Comment: +1 Be aware that Windows guru Raymond Chen points out that this `AttachThreadInput` workaround [can cause your program to stop responding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8081858/15639) in some circumstances. However I've never encountered these bugs myself. YMMV.

Comment: @MarkJ: what about the approach taken in my comment above?

Comment: @CJ7 I  saw that, what were the results? ps this [VB6 Froms contain c# forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953725/contain-a-vb6-form-in-a-net-mdi) and vice versa is why I wish to know.

Comment: @CJ7 Sounds promising. It doesn't use `AttachThreadInput` so Raymond's warnings don't apply. Let us know if it works - if it does work post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @CJ7 +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using the [NativeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.NATIVEWINDOW.#CTOR%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) class, following the last answer in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2692df26-317c-4415-816b-d08fe6854df8/vbnet-vb6-win32-api-problems?forum=vbinterop

That code uses `FindWindowEx` to get the handle of the `VB6` window, which is unecessary because you can simply pass the handle of the `VB6` window to the `.NET` form:

```
public void ShowDotNetForm(IntPtr hwndMain) 
{
    NativeWindow vb6Window = new NativeWindow();
    vb6Window.AssignHandle(hwndMain);
    f.Show(vb6Window);
}
```

The code in the `VB6` form is:

```
dotNetObj.ShowDotNetForm Me.hWnd
```

Passing the window handle from `VB6` is better because `FindWindowEx` requires you to know the text of the window title to get the handle.