# How to display VB6 forms from a .NET application

Tags: .net, vb6, interop

I am wondering if there exists a way to load/open/close forms created with VB6 within a .NET application. Microsoft distributes an InterOpForms toolkit, but advocates it as a way to embed .NET WinForms into a VB6 application. My aim would be to acheive the converse, that the .NET runtime opens and closes forms defined in the VB application.

I am probably missing something, since I wasn't able to find the right words to Google a solution for this. Is it so obvious that nobody ever asked the question? Is the VB runtime able to run as a companion of a .NET application?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19368/Embedding-of-VB6-form-in-NET-applications and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953725/contain-a-vb6-form-in-a-net-mdi

Comment: @EkoostikMartin CodeProject article could be useful, but the StackOverflow question that you've linked is about embedding a VB6 form into a .Net **MDI** form, which is more challenging and specialised.

Comment: Sure, if the OP wants to display multiple forms at the same time he may want to use MDI. I still think it might be useful.

Comment: It is most certainly possible to do what you are asking at least as far .net Winforms VB6 interop goes, however, unless you find a library to facilitate it, you will end up learning how to work with window handles.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: So it's all about opening the form as an ActiveX. Excellent. My use case is exactly that, gradually migrating a VB app into unit-tested .NET.

Answer (score 0):

u can complied vb6 forms to exe and call in .net by parameters to want .
foe example vb6projected.exe /sample